# jsonwebtoken.verify() working on Postman but not in localhost using Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt

```
app.get("/expenses", async (req, res) => {
    const token = req.cookies.jwt;
    if (token) {
        jwt.verify(token, SIGN, async (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                res.clearCookie('jwt');
                res.status(400).send({ error: "Please login to view expenses" });
            }
            else {
                let id = decodedToken.id;
                let user = await User.findById(id);
                let username = user.username;
                const expenses = await Expense.find({ user_name: username }).sort({ date_recorded: -1 });
                if (expenses) {
                    res.status(201).send(expenses);
                }
                else {
                    res.status(201).send({ error: "No expenses to show" });
                }
            }
        })
    }
    else {
        res.status(400).send({ error: "Please login to view expenses" });
    }
})
```

The above code checks whether a JWT authentication cookie is valid and then fetches the corresponding user's expenses based on the username associated with those expenses. The above code reads and evaluates the cookies properly on postman, but fails on my localhost in the browser. Is there anything I can do to make it work with the browser??

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The browser sends cookie in below format in the request header

cookie: "cookiename1=value1;cookiename2=value2"

Parse the above header to get the required cookie.

```
const getCookiesFromRequest = (req) => {
  const cookies = {}
  const cookieStrings = req.headers.cookie.split(';');
  cookieStrings.forEach((each) => {
    const cookiePart = each.split('=')
    cookies[cookiePart[0].trim()] = cookiePart[1].trim()
  })
  return cookies
}

const cookies = getCookiesFromRequest(req)
const token = cookies['jwt']
```

Comment: It is still not working, it says "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')". It says req.headers.cookie is undefined even though the cookie is set properly in the browser.

Comment: @Sudheer2701 Could you please post your request headers? want to check whether the cookie is being sent in the request or not.